# This RelativeLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm developing an Android 3.1. and above application.

On one activity I generate its layout dynamically. I'm using **formdetail.xml** as contentview:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.formdetail);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {
        currentFormId = extras.getString("FormId");
    }
}
```

formdetail.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/detailLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/downloadFormsButton"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/download_forms_button" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/formErrorMsg"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp" >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

`downloadFormsButton` and `formErrorMsg` must be always in form.

But using that xml I get this warning:

`This RelativeLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless`

I need linearLayout to add TableLayouts programmatically.

How can I solve this warning?

Comment: I think your parent layout wrap only one child and you can optimize your layout by removing parent LinearLayout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You either ignore it or right click your project. Click `Build Path->Configure Build Path...`. Under `Android Lint Preferences` look for `UselessParent` and set it's severity to ignore or click `Ignore All`.

EDIT:

I take that last part back.  I think `Ignore All` will wipe all Lint warnings and errors.

Comment: In Eclipse Juno is this menu is located in your Project's Properties->Android Lint Preferences

Answer (score 14):

Lint is correct in it's warning, your LinearLayout isn't doing anything useful, since its only child is a RelativeLayout.  Remove the LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/detailLayout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <Button android:id="@+id/downloadFormsButton" 
         android:enabled="false"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_margin="10dp"
         android:text="@string/download_forms_button" />
 <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/formErrorMsg" 
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:padding="10dp"
         android:textSize="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As you can read in my question, I need a LinearLayout to add TableLayouts programmatically.

Comment: then you can add those to your RelativeLayout ... either way I was merely explaining the reason for the Lint warning

Answer (score 2):

I was also having the same issue with my app layout.

I don't know how and it is right way or not, but this get resolved after setting background attribute to both layouts.

Now there is no warning and working perfect. Hope it will also work for you.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_BookImage"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:contentDescription="@string/India"
                android:src="@drawable/india" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I had two linear layouts that the linter recognized as redundant, but the first one holds a background image that is fixed to the screen origins, the second layout places some input fields and texts centered as a group horizontally and vertically. I couldn't find a way of having that without using the two layouts, so defining the android:background attributes of both layouts eliminated the warning.

Answer (score 1):

That is just an warning from `lint`. `Lint` doesn't know you would later append views to this layout and it will warn you that you added an unnecessary extra view(increasing your layout depth).

You should just ignore the warning(If it really bothers you here is a link on [how to remove warnings](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings) from `lint`).