# Linear and Relative Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show a button bar at the end of my activity. I created a layout named: batton_bar_ref.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_blue_light_horizental_gradiant_notrounded"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pay_button"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:text="@string/pay"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And add it with `<include layout="@layout/button_bar_ref"/>` to another layout.

It is showing a warning message :

```
This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless; transfer the background attribute to the other view.
```

Could you let me know how can I fix it?

Addenda :

1. button bar should be at the end of screen.
2. Note that Linear layout has a background.

Comment: possible duplicate of [This RelativeLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319947/this-relativelayout-layout-or-its-linearlayout-parent-is-useless)

Comment: This looks like something that Android Lint would complain about.  If you need to achieve this particular layout for your project, you should just ignore the warning.

Answer (score 2):

It is just suggestion to optimize your layout by removing tags that are not required.  In your case since you do not have any children under RelativeLayout other than LinearLayout, this particular layout is not really correctly designed.

First you can ignore this warning, and once you have successfully designed the layout file in which you are planning to include this layout file, you will realize that one of the layouts declared in this file can be eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the relative layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_blue_light_horizental_gradiant_notrounded"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pay_button"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:text="@string/pay"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Then the button bar will not be at the end of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the `RelativeLayout` tag from the xml file

Comment: I did, but then the button bar with background will not be at the end of screen.

Comment: @Ali then remove then `LinearLayout` from the xml. Actually the warning doesn't matter. Its just for the performance issue.

Comment: Check the question please : `Note that Linear layout has a background.` I can´t put the background on Relative layout since it takes whole the screen, not the end of screen.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is triggered, when a Layout has only one child that is also a Layout. In this case one of both can be removed without any problems. It is recommended to remove these redundant layouts as they reduce the overall performance of the UI.

In your case there is no use of RelativeLayout. There will be no change if you remove this. So this warning is showing. But this is just a warning. There is no harm in using this

Comment: Then the button bar will not be at the end of the screen.

Comment: oh that is a good point @Ali.. you can remove the first LinearLayout.. .. and ifyou are not comfortable you can use the current xml ..

Answer (score 0):

Please use bellow code fix your issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/pay_button"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/pay"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</Button>
```

Comment: As you can see the Linear layout have a background. What happen for that?