# I'm using the following code on ADK to make some text roll but always get the same error. Any tip?

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll

I always get the "This ScrollView layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless" error.

Here's the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</ScrollView>



   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to be a real error but a lint tool error. You can just suppress it.

Comment: You might want to check out if [this thread on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319947/this-relativelayout-layout-or-its-linearlayout-parent-is-useless) is similar to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lint waring, and not an error. It's just saying, that it seems like you don't need the `RelativeLayout` or the `ScrollView`.

If you are not dynamically adding anything to your `RelativeLayout` or using it in any other way, then you can remove it since it serves no propose:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</ScrollView>
```