# This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless; transfer the background attribute to the other view warning

Tags: android, android-layout

not sure what I am doing wrong, nothing complicated 2 buttons inside a LinearLayout and I get
"This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless; transfer the background attribute to the other view" warning....here is the code, is boggling my mind

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/GCBS_Template_BKGND"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Partfinder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Part Finder" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Heaterfinder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Heater Finder" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [This RelativeLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319947/this-relativelayout-layout-or-its-linearlayout-parent-is-useless)

Comment: Accepted answer in that question just hides the warning. I don't say you cannot ignore the warning but there is a reason you get that. Your relative layout only holds another layout. The warning means one of them is useless and you can remove one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show two buttons vertically - there's no need to use the LinearLayout in this case. This is increasing your view level hierarchy- that's why the warning is shown.

You can simply use android:layout_below="@+id/Partfinder" to your 2nd button to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Juno, you can Project's Properties -> Android Lint Preferences. Now, Look for UselessParent and set it's severity to ignore or click Ignore All.
But at the end, Your problem is your RelativeLayout only have one child. You can remove it like that:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/GCBS_Template_BKGND"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Partfinder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Part Finder" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Heaterfinder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Heater Finder" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is very clear as per your xml layout creation. For just adding 2 buttons you may not need both Relative & Linear Layout but only one of the layouts is more than enough. So, by deleting the Linear Layout in your XML should help you proceed further like below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/GCBS_Template_BKGND"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Partfinder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Part Finder" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Heaterfinder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Heater Finder" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

After this just drag and drop the buttons in layout view of the xml and position them wherever you want the buttons. That should put the XML script automatically in your XML file.